# Is this even possible?  Further MySQL query in connection with Left Join

Tags: mysql, join, count, left-join

Previous question linky: [MySQL Left Joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9020667/mysql-left-joins)

Very kindly we got the following code working:

```
select
      JustACME.Name,
      JustACME.NameCount,
      COALESCE( COUNT( * ), 0 ) as CountFromResultsTable
   from
      ( select a.Name,
               count(*) as NameCount
           from
              acme a
           group by
              a.Name ) JustACME

      LEFT JOIN results r
         on JustACME.Name = r.Name
   group by
      JustACME.Name
```

The above code works exactly as we need and brings back the following

```
Name     Count     Total
Tom      10        5
Bon      9         4
```

In addition to that information being in the `acme` and `results` table, we also need to bring back further information.  The 'results' table is as follows:

```
Name     q1
Tom      1
Tom      2
Tom      1
Bob      3
Bob      2
Bob      1
Bob      2
```

I'd like to add to this query, in the talble called `results` there is another field called `q1`.  This can have a number in it, either 1, 2, or 3 - what I'd like to do is bring back the number of times that 1,2 or 3 appears (count) for each of the `Name` that also appear in the table.  Make sense?

Basically, the output of the query should be something like this:

```
Name     Count     Total     q1 = 1    q1 = 2     q1 = 3
Bob      9         4         1         2          1
Tom      10        5         4         1          0
```

I'm probably going out on a limb here but can it be done???

Thanks in advance,

H.

Comment: It doesn't hurt to link to previous questions that got you to this point.

Comment: That's been added Sonny - also further details of what we are looking for.

Comment: You have an error there: `COALESCE( COUNT( * ), 0 )` should be `COALESCE( COUNT( r.Name ), 0 )`. You get wrong results (count=1 instead of 0) for names that are not in the `result` table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get just the `Name, q1=1, q1=2, q1=3` table from `results` only you can use:

```
SELECT Name,
       COUNT(IF(q1=1,1,NULL)) as q1is1, 
       COUNT(IF(q1=2,1,NULL)) as q1is2,
       COUNT(IF(q1=3,1,NULL)) as q1is3
FROM results
GROUP BY Name
```

This counts up the number of occurences of each result (per Name) -- this works because you only want three extra columns and know inadvance which values of q1 you want to have a columns. (If there were say half a million q1 values there's no way to do this in MySQL other than writing out the `COUNT(IF(q1=i,1,0)) AS q1isi` half a million times -- not exactly ideal).

To combine with your previous query, perhaps something like this (add it in as a `JOIN`):

```
select
  JustACME.Name,
  JustACME.NameCount,
  COALESCE( COUNT( * ), 0 ) as CountFromResultsTable,
  r2.q1is1, r2.q1is2, r2.q1is3                     -- <-- grab those extra rows
from
  ( select a.Name,
           count(*) as NameCount
       from
          acme a
       group by
          a.Name ) JustACME

  LEFT JOIN results r
     on JustACME.Name = r.Name
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT Name,                          -- <-- add the new table in
                 COUNT(IF(q1=1,1,NULL)) as q1is1, 
                 COUNT(IF(q1=2,1,NULL)) as q1is2,
                 COUNT(IF(q1=3,1,NULL)) as q1is3
             FROM results
             GROUP BY Name) r2
     ON JustACME.Name = r2.Name
group by
  JustACME.Name
```

In fact, I'm sure there's a way to do this without needing to `LEFT JOIN` on a sub-query, but my mysql kung fu has run out :P

Comment: Thanks for that, it is very close to being correct.  However, that new code (the bit added to the existing query) brings back the same counts as for each q1 option, which isn't correct.  In fact it brings back the same count as the number if times 'name' appears in results :(  Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, does the query on its own work (`SELECT Name ... FROM results GROUP BY name`)? - I'll try to mash up a toy database to play with when I get home.

Comment: Nope, ran the straight query and not working - that might be the issue :) thanks in advance! :-)

Comment: @Homer_J - fixed it and updated answer -- the problem was `COUNT(IF(q1=1,1,0))` should have been `COUNT(IF(q1=1,1,NULL))`, because `COUNT(0)` is still 1! (there's one zero in there) -- whereas `COUNT(NULL)` is 0 because there's nothing to count.

Comment: `IF(q1=1,1,NULL)` can also be written `CASE WHEN q1=1 THEN 1 END`

Comment: @mathematical.coffee - OK, that new, updated code, just brings backs '0' for everything - still not right :-(.  Any ideas?

Comment: @mathematical.coffee - Oh and the updated simple query doesn't work either :(

Comment: Hmm the updated simple query worked for me - see [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc235/1). When you say "doesn't work" what do you mean?

Comment: Re combinng the simple query into the big query, I don't know how to help you further without some reproducible sample data to play with. Sorry :(